# HTML Form Submission and JSP mySQL

Tags: html, jsp

I recently made an HTML page that validates the form submission so that the submission has values for name, email address, gender, comments, and same passwords. Right now, I'm trying to implement so these values for each form can be inserted into a database. Below are snippets of the code

HTML portion

```
    <form id="regForm" action="insertInfo.jsp" onsubmit="return validation();" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Registration</legend>
            <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></p>
            <p>Email Address: <input type="text" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress"/></p>
            <p>Gender: 
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderM" value="Male" /> Male
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderF" value="Female" /> Female
            </p>
            <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password_1" id="password_1"/></p>
            <p>Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="password_2" id="password_2"/></p>
            <p>Comments: <input type="text" name="comments" id="comments"/></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

JSP code named as insertInfo.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%
   String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://sql.school.edu:3306/user";
   Connection connection = null;
   Statement statement = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "user", "password");
   statement = connection.createStatement();
   String name=request.getParameter("name");
   String password=request.getParameter("password_1");
   String email=request.getParameter("emailAddress");
   String gender=request.getParameter("gender");
   String comments=request.getParameter("comments"); 
   rs = statement.executeQuery("INSERT INTO Information VALUES ('"+name+"', '"+password+"', '"+email+"', '"+gender="', '"+comments+"')");
%>
```

When I try to submit a form, I get prompted to a page similar to

> HTTP Status 404 - /~user/insertInfo.jsp
>
> type Status report
>
> message /~user/insertInfo.jsp
>
> description The requested resource (/~user/insertInfo.jsp) is not
>   available. Apache Tomcat/5.5.29

I'm confused as to why this is occurring. Also, the HTML and JSP file are in the same public_html directory.

Comment: where do your html page and insertInfo.jsp page locate?

Comment: can you please tell me what is you actual proble?

Comment: Both files are located in the same directory so say the html file is called form.html it would /~user/form.html and similarly /~user/insertInfo.jsp

Comment: can you show us the validation function contents..